# E-mails with working forms - possible?

Tags: html, email, forms, action

Is it possible to send an e-mail with a `<form>` in it that the receiver can fill out and send? The form will obviously have an external absolute path to the processing file (action), e.g. http://mysite.com/processor.php.

Just `Yes` - `No` answers will not suffice.

By possible I mean will all e-mail clients `like` this and allow mails to pass through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it *is* possible, but you need to provide an alternative functionality unless you have full control on the software that will be used to process the e-mail (for instance, a custom web client that's part of a ticket system or a desktop client in an enterprise environment). There're *many* e-mail clients out there and not all of them implement form handling (and even those who do may not do it properly).

Tests with the clients I use:

- Outlook Express: GET works, POST sends no data
- Gmail: GET and POST work

Answer (score 2):

You can't count on the client to display HTML/javascript/.. content. You could do it, if you also provide a link to a webpage with the same content for people whose client does not display the form.

Comment: Also, even when the client does support HTML, typically it is a restricted subset of HTML.

Comment: And I've never seen one that supported JS (except via security holes that were later patched)

Comment: I'm not talking about JS. That gets restricted by many e-mail clients.